# Sumar 2 elementos de una lista y agregar el resultado a otra lista

Tags: lista, kotlin

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en Kotlin, el cual me pide lo siguiente: **Dada una lista o array de números, se pide recorrer los elementos de la
lista y almacenar en otra lista el resultado de sumar ese elemento con el
anterior.
Por ejemplo, dada la lista: [1, 2, 3, 4], se espera que la salida sea una lista
con los elementos [3, 5, 7]**

Si bien pude lograr una especie de solución, la misma no sería la ideal ya que funciona con una lista de cierta longitud únicamente, por ende agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

```
fun Ej2() {
    var lista = listOf(2,4,6,8)
    var lista2 = listOf(lista.get(1)+lista.get(0),lista.get(2)+lista.get(1),lista.get(3)+lista.get(2))
    println(lista2)
}
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de que los arreglos se recorran de esa manera en Kotlin.

Comment: Seguramente sea con un FOR, pero aún así se me dificulta la lógica dentro del mismo

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar la suma puedes iterar cada elemento y sumarlo con su correspondiente siguiente elemento. El valor del siguiente elemento lo puedes obtener mediante el indice.

```
 var lista = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
 var indexCounter = 0

 var listaSuma : Array<Int> = arrayOf()
  for (element in lista) {         
       indexCounter = indexCounter.inc()
       if(indexCounter < lista.size)
         //Suma elemento mas siguiente elemento.         
         listaSuma += (element + lista[indexCounter])       
   }
 
println(listaSuma.toList())
```

Salida:

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera más sencilla de hacerlo en una sola línea y al estilo `Kotlin` es usar un simple `map`:

```
val result = (1 until lista.size).map { lista[it-1] + lista[it] }
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes testear en el [Playground de Kotlin](https://pl.kotl.in/oYSiKmQl4).